# Is this character supposed to be the Devil?

Tags: 666-park-avenue

[image: 666 Park Avenue] <sup>[[Source](http://www.moviepilot.de/serie/666-park-avenue/bilder/8415925)]</sup>

About the TV series [**666 Park Avenue**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2197797/):

> At *666 Park Avenue*, all of your dreams and burning desires can come true: wealth, sex, love, power, even revenge. But just be careful what you wish for, because the price you pay... could be your soul.
>
> Welcome to *The Drake*, the premiere apartment building on Manhattan's Upper East Side. Owned by the mysterious **Gavin Doran** and his sexy wife Olivia, *The Drake* is home to dozens of residents who are unaware they're living in the dark embrace of supernatural forces.

I'm wondering if the *"666"* is supposed to be a hint that the *Devil* is at play, or if it's just meant as a general reference for "evil"?

Is the rich, powerful and ruthless *Gavin Doran* supposed to be the Devil?

Comment: P.S.: I avoided naming the character in the title because of _Spoilers_.

Comment: Highly doubt he is the actual devil. He has fear Of certain evils himself, which the devil obviously Wouldn't have! Jmo though..

Comment: It is my opinion he is a sort of "crossroads demon" who grants wishes at high costs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The show is deliberately vague** on whether or not Terry O'Quinn's character is the devil -- it's likely that's one of the hooks the show's writers are playing with in their plot arcing.

In many settings, this question has been brought up, and answers are purposefully inconclusive ... for example, **Terry O'Quinn, at *Comic Con*, said**:

> *“He seems, at the moment, pretty evil . . . He doesn’t seem like he’d slow down for a baby in a carriage.”*

Executive producer **David Wilcox also said**:

> *“He’s not who you’d expect . . . It’ll take some times to figure out who he is.”*

(both quotes from an [**Entertainment Weekly**](http://insidetv.ew.com/2012/07/13/666-park-comic-con-terry-oquinn/) article)

Other promotional materials will say things like *"He's positively devilish"* and other vague phrases.

It might be useful to think of some of the tropes that this show is relying on in trying to guess the answer to your question -- things like *Faust,* for example. Of course, the show could either be playing to such a trope, or against it, so there's still no definitive answer -- but it's certainly relevant.

Comment: Looks like this is only going to get a 13 episode run, really hoping they provide some answers in the finale but not expecting it to happen.